# Plot raster in R with boundaries matching limits arguments

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a raster image that I would like to plot with a world map overlay in R. I am able to plot both the raster image and map overlay, but the x and y limits specified for the raster plot are not what I specified, leaving an overhang outside of the raster bounds that I do not want displayed on my map.

Here is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(rworldmap)

r <- raster(ncol=500, nrow=500)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
plot(r, ylim=c(-50,50), xlim=c(-100,100), col=rev(pal(100)))
world <- getMap(resolution="high")
map(world, add=TRUE, lwd=0.5)
```

Which produces this map:

[image]

Any ideas for how to get rid of the white non-raster overhangs running along the top and bottom of the figure? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example is a slight modification of your code.

```
library(raster)
library(rworldmap)
library(rgeos)

r <- raster(ncol=500, nrow=500)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
r <- crop(r, extent(-100, 100, -50, 50))
world <- getMap(resolution="high")
world <- gBuffer(world, byid = T, width = 0)
world <- crop(world, r)
png(file = "C:/Example_Plot.png", height = 500, width = 880)
plot(r)
plot(world, add = T, lwd = 0.5)
dev.off()
```

The strategy is essentially to crop the polygons to the extent of the raster object and to specify the width and height of the output file.

[image: Example_Plot]